# Open .fit image file

Tags: qgis, remote-sensing, file-formats

I am trying to open an image file with the extension ".fit". Does anybody know which software to use?

I obtained this image using the WASI software (Water Color Simulator) available on the IOCCG website (http://ioccg.org/resources/software/).

The contents of the image file are described by a additional ".hdr" file. The image file contains several bands, corresponding to the different parameters of the water (constituant concentration, bottom depth, etc) computed by the software.

It would be great if I could open this image with QGIS.

So far I have found this list of image viewers (https://fits.gsfc.nasa.gov/fits_viewer.html), but none of those that I tried have worked yet.

Comment: Please don't thank in advance, please give thanks by voting on answers

Comment: As FITS is a format supported by GDAL ~ http://www.gdal.org/frmt_various.html#FITS did you try  in QGIS using the Open a GDAL supported Raster Data CSource option?

Comment: @nmtoken just came across this question again, it seems I missed your comment. QGIS worked for me with the GDAL supported Raster Data Source option (default raster opening option in my version of QGIS). It you want to post your comment as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As FITS is a format supported by GDAL ~ [gdal.org/frmt_various.html#FITS](https://www.gdal.org/frmt_various.html#FITS) you should be able in QGIS to use the Open a GDAL supported Raster Data CSource option.